# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str' django setting.py

Tags: django, django-models, django-settings

when im taking my course of django i got this error i don't know how to fix it here is my settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to remove / and + like this

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR + 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The tutorial you are following has used a [`pathlib.Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) object for `BASE_DIR` which supports the `/` operator for joining paths. You need to either use `pathlib` or use [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) if you use strings

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

Comment: its an databases error you don's see my code first see my code

Comment: @PatroLevis I have edited the answer to include the entire DATABASES setting now... You will need to `import os` at the top of your settings file